# Why does react context needs a provider?

Tags: reactjs

Context state can just be an observable and update components who subscribe like the observer pattern.

If you need the context state in a component just subscribe to a specific context.

Why do we need to render the context provider at the root of the app in order to use it somewhere else?

I ask since i see many libraries and apps use context now as the main way to share state between components but I don't understand the need to render the provider at the root of the app since each shared state (context) could be initialized outside of render functions

I made an npm package that does something similar in order to simplify the context/shared states of an app as an example of what i mean

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jstates
And a package for react bindings
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jstates-react

Comment: `Why do we need to render the context provider at the root` - we don't. We can render context providers anywhere (above the consumer).

Answer (score 2):

The reason is IMHO is recat tries to follow a paradigm where you don't have global state. 
In general you want state to be as local as possible. 
This allows better testing where you can feed mock state into the provider easily.

If you have a global object where everyone subscribe to it would be unclear where state is coming from. 
With the context provider it very clear and state is encapsulated inside the component tree (no global objects).

Comment: But you don't need a provider for that, you could simply create an observable (not a global state) and share to the components that need it instead of pushing the context through the tree

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's obeservable or not. Where would you put it? How would you encapsulate it so that it's not global?

Comment: You can see one solution in the packages i shared in the question. Hope it helps to understand how it can work, IMO also simpler

Comment: I looked at it. Say I `createState` . How would I pass a reference of the state instance into my component? If using import from another file - that is exactly global state.

Answer (score 1):

Context API has to support multiple instances of the same context provider (e.g. while migrating part of the project to a new version of some library).

Even if libraries that use Context are most often *used* as singletons (for managing global state), when [Thinking in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html), authors need to support composable Components, not just global singletons. React API design also prefers Components over other patterns when feasible (e.g. `<Suspense />` and `<Provider />`, but not life cycle hooks).

When designing support of multiple instances, some pattern for inversion of control is advisable for easier debugging (more constrains == less things that could go wrong).

Thus, explicit visibility in the React Components tree is preferred (notice that even life cycle methods and hooks are visible in the tree node details - but you only need to see those for a single node, not to identify "all children that have access to this context").

Comment: But anyway you use the context internally, you could just listen to the context change and initiate it/change it somewhere else with more control outside of the render functions

Comment: more control like what? I am not aware of any useful pattern that would be possible but isn't possible already..

Comment: the data provider behind context can use any observables or initialization it wants, it's just interface to React that has to use the <Provider />